# Details of "updating reference table"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I am running the following one-off query to update about 25M rows, so I expect it will take quite a bit to do:

```
UPDATE ghl_map JOIN ghu USING (location)
SET ghu.location_country=ghl_map.location_country
```

There is an index on both tables' `location` field and I've run a few tests with a small sample size to confirm it's using the index. Now when I run the query, it produces the following output via `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`:

```
 Time   State                        Info
 2422   updating reference tables   UPDATE ghl_map join ghu...
```

What exactly does `updating references tables` mean or do in a mysql update statement? I am currently using mysql5.7 and the table has no FKs, one index on `location`, and no indexes on any of the fields being updated.

All it says in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-thread-states.html) are:

> **updating reference tables**
>
> The server is executing the second part of a multiple-table update and updating the matched rows from the other tables.

Comment: It's updating the rows in the `ghu` table as you asked it to.

Comment: @Barmar so in this case `reference` just means the source table, that is the `lhs` of the `SET` clause?

Comment: It means the rows in the destination table that are matched in the join.